# Ruby - undefined method `fdiv' for 0:Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Over the weekend, for some reason, one of our servers has decided to start throwing the following errors (nothing has changed).  Any ideas?:

```
/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  09:57:05 AM Mon, 29 Jun 2009
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  undefined method `fdiv' for 0:Fixnum
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml/rubytypes.rb:146:in `is_binary_data?'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml/rubytypes.rb:165:in `to_yaml'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:391:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:391:in `emit'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:391:in `quick_emit'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml/rubytypes.rb:164:in `to_yaml'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml/rubytypes.rb:41:in `node_export'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml/rubytypes.rb:41:in `add'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml/rubytypes.rb:41:in `to_yaml'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml/rubytypes.rb:40:in `each'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml/rubytypes.rb:40:in `to_yaml'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml/rubytypes.rb:39:in `map'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml/rubytypes.rb:39:in `to_yaml'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:391:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:391:in `emit'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:391:in `quick_emit'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml/rubytypes.rb:38:in `to_yaml'
    /var/www/xxx/releases/20090625091954/vendor/plugins/hoptoad_notifier/lib/hoptoad_notifier.rb:338:in `send_to_hoptoad'
    /var/www/xxx/releases/20090625091954/vendor/plugins/hoptoad_notifier/lib/hoptoad_notifier.rb:235:in `notify_hoptoad'
    /var/www/xxx/releases/20090625091954/vendor/plugins/hoptoad_notifier/lib/hoptoad_notifier.rb:225:in `rescue_action_in_public'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.2/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:154:in `rescue_action_without_handler'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.2/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:74:in `rescue_action_without_newrelic_trace'
    /var/www/xxx/releases/20090625091954/vendor/plugins/newrelic_rpm/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails/errors.rb:14:in `rescue_action'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:523:in `send'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.2/lib/action_controller/base.rb:523:in `process_without_filters'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.2/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.2/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:65:in `call_with_exception'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:91:in `dispatch_without_newrelic'
    /var/www/xxx/releases/20090625091954/vendor/plugins/newrelic_rpm/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/dispatcher_instrumentation.rb:44:in `dispatch'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:111:in `_call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:82:in `initialize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.2/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.2/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.2/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.2/lib/action_controller/rewindable_input.rb:25:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.2/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:93:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.2/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:11:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.2/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.2/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.2/lib/action_controller/vendor/rack-1.0/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.2/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.2/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:81:in `process_request'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:203:in `main_loop'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.2/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:340:in `start_request_handler'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.2/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:298:in `handle_spawn_application'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.2/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:181:in `safe_fork'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.2/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:296:in `handle_spawn_application'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:337:in `__send__'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:337:in `main_loop'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:187:in `start_synchronously'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:154:in `start'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.2/lib/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:192:in `start'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.2/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:257:in `spawn_rails_application'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:126:in `lookup_or_add'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.2/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:251:in `spawn_rails_application'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:80:in `synchronize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.2/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:250:in `spawn_rails_application'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.2/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:153:in `spawn_application'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.2/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:282:in `handle_spawn_application'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:337:in `__send__'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:337:in `main_loop'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.2/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:187:in `start_synchronously'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.2/bin/passenger-spawn-server:61
```

Comment: Which version of ruby do you have installed on that server ? Can you provide other environment related details as well ?

Comment: No, you're wrong. If it wasn't doing it before but is now, then something *has* changed. Your quest should be to find out what that is :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check ruby version on this server and the other servers

Its possible Yaml.rb file is of ruby 1.8.7  to the installed ruby version that probably is 1.8.6.(I am not entirely sure)

Try reinstalling ruby on the System.

HTH